# Query contain more then one value when it used as a expression

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, stored-procedures

I have one Table

**tblTimeSlotInformation**(Username, EmpName, Date(date), Day, StartingTime(time(7)), EndingTime(time(7)), TimeSlot, Topic, ClassroomNo)

Data can't insert if StartingTime is between StartingTime and EndingTime which are already store. Ex : 13.30(StartingTime) to 14.30(EndingTime) time store in database then user try to insert 13:45(StartingTime) to 15:45(EndingTIme) but message display that "These time slot is already exist"

**Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE Proc spStoreTimeSlotDetails        
@Username nvarchar(50),        
@EmpName nvarchar(50),        
@Date date,        
@Day nvarchar(50),        
@ST time(7),        
@ET time(7),        
@TimeSlot nvarchar(50),        
@Topic nvarchar(50),        
@ClassroomNo int         
as          
begin          
--Declare @count int          
Declare @ReturnCode int        
Declare @MinuteDiff int       
DECLARE @i int = 1      
Declare @NewTime time(7)      
Declare @CRN int    
Declare @D date    

set @ReturnCode=0  
set @MinuteDiff=(select DATEDIFF(MINUTE,StartingTime,EndingTime) from tblTimeSlotDetails)      
set @NewTime=(select StartingTime from tblTimeSlotDetails)  
set @CRN=(Select ClassroomNo from tblTimeSlotDetails)    
set @D=(select [Date] from tblTimeSlotDetails)    

WHILE @i <= @MinuteDiff   
BEGIN      
 set @NewTime=(select DATEADD(MINUTE,1,@NewTime) from tblTimeSlotDetails)    
 if(@CRN=@ClassroomNo and @D=@Date and @NewTime=@ST and @ST=)          
 Begin          
  set @ReturnCode=-1   
  break         
 end          
 else          
 Begin          
  set @ReturnCode=1         
 end          
 SET @i = @i + 1      
End      
if(@ReturnCode=1 or @ReturnCode=0)    
begin   
 Insert into tblTimeSlotDetails values(@Username,@EmpName,@Date,@Day,@ST,@ET,@TimeSlot,@Topic,@ClassroomNo)          
end    
select @ReturnCode as ReturnValue   
end
```

but every time when I run my **Asp.net c# application** error prompt
***"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression"***

How Should I write my query?

Comment: when you are setting the variable values using select query one of them is returning more than one value. You need to change the select query and fetch the only single value like this "Select top 1 columnname  from tablename"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Error: Subquery returned more than 1 value.

*Suspected statement causing error*

```
set @NewTime=(select StartingTime from tblTimeSlotDetails)
```

You are getting problem due to multiple results being return by query that could not be assigned to single variable i.e. `@NewTime` You probably need to get the row with `maximum` time which could be take using max() function.

```
set @NewTime=(select Max(StartingTime) from tblTimeSlotDetails)
```

Comment: can you please write whole Stored Procedure? I am new in database.

Comment: It is not possible for me and this wont help you in real sense. I can guide you to make it easy by debugging if your database in not the production, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272701(v=vs.103).aspx

Answer (score 0):

**if(@CRN=@ClassroomNo and @D=@Date and @NewTime=@ST)**

just update below line code and get result as you wish your requirement.

```
if(@CRN=@ClassroomNo and @D=@Date and @NewTime=@ST and @ST=)
```

---